# Using 5x5 Color Matrix for Bitmap

Tags: android, image-processing

I have a method that will add an effect to a bitmap using the color filter. Ex:

```
public static Bitmap changeContrast(Bitmap bmp, float contrast)
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, contrast, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });

    return getBitmapFromColorMatrix(cm, bmp);
}
```

However, I want to use a sharpening filter matrix:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  
 0 -1 -1 -1  0
 0 -1  9 -1  0
 0 -1 -1 -1  0 
 0  0  0  0  0
```

But ColorMatrix only accepts 4x5 matrix array. Is there a way that I could use the 5x5 matrix with my bitmap?

What I tried:

I tried using the `ScriptIntrinsicConvolve5x5` class but it requires API17 and above but i need to use api down to API14. How can i achieve this. Please help.

UPDATE:

This is the code for getBitmapFromColorMatrix() , this might be helpful.

```
    static Bitmap getBitmapFromColorMatrix (ColorMatrix cm, Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
       Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), sourceBitmap.getConfig());

       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

       Paint paint = new Paint();
       paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
       canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

       return ret;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old, but if you're still interested, as you noted, [ColorMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html) uses a 4x5 matrix, primarily because the 5th row is not used. [ScriptIntrinsicConvolve5x5](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicConvolve5x5.html) is not what you're looking for. As noted by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27454681/852795, "Convolve5x5 is a fundamentally different operation that doesn't support different constants per channel. ColorMatrix is really the operation you want and should be fast."

Looking at your "sharpening filter matrix", your bottom row is all zeros, so you should be able to ignore it. Try removing that and pumping in the 4x5 matrix to see if that works.

```
public static Bitmap sharpeningFilter(Bitmap bmp)
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                    0, -1, 9, -1, 0,
                    0, -1, -1, -1, 0
            });

    return getBitmapFromColorMatrix(cm, bmp);
}
```

By the way, if you want to sharpen and contrast at the same time, you can concatenate the ColorMatrices with `cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));` before using `ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);` and then `Paint.setColorFilter()`.

Lastly, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15119089/852795 for a great `ColorMatix` resouce for brightness, contrast, saturation and hue. You'll notice @Pablo uses 5x5 matrices, but the 5th row is always `0, 0, 0, 0, 1` and thus irrelevant which is fine because it's ignored anyway.